# Angular material tablas dinámicas. Pasar valores con sub claves

Tags: angular, tablas, material

Al crear una tabla dinámica me encuentro con el siguiente problema, los valores que pertenecen a claves con subclave no los procesa. (por ejemplo: "vehiculos.turismo")

```
let datos = [
    {
        "ciudad": "Bembibre",
        "vehiculos":{
            "turismo": "30",
            "todoterreno": "40",
            "camiones": "20"
        }
    },
    {
        "ciudad": "Camponaraya",
        "vehiculos":{
            "turismo": "34",
            "todoterreno":"22",
            "camiones": "10"
        }
    },
        {
        "ciudad": "Benuza",
        "vehiculos":{
            "turismo": "43",
            "todoterreno":"20",
            "camiones": "11"
        }
    }
]
```

tablaejemplodinamica.ts

```
// defino los campos 
columnas:['ciudad', 'vehiculos.turismo', 'vehiculos.todoterreno', "vehiculos.camiones"]
```

Si la construyo de esta forma sí procesa los datos.
tablaestatica.component.html

```html
<!-- tablaestatica.component.html -->

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> {{element["ciudad"]}}</td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
</mat-table>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> {{element["vehiculos.turismo"]}}</td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
</mat-table>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> {{element["vehiculos.todoterreno"]}}</td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
</mat-table>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> {{element["vehiculos.camiones"]}}</td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

Si la construyo dinámica no procesa los datos:

tabladinamica.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna" *ngFor="let columna of columnas;">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=dataIndex;"> {{element[columna]}}</td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
```

Versión Angular material 9.0.0

Comment: no entiendo lo que haces en `tablaestatica.component.html`. Porque defines una tabla por cada dato, tampoco especificas la columna a renderizar solo pones `[matColumnDef]="columna"` y `columna` que es?

Comment: Cierto, fue un error en el copia y pega, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes en los data-binding

```
tabladinamica.component.html
```

La parte modificada sería esta:

```
{{element[<b>{{</b>columna<b>}}</b>]}}
```

quedando el código así:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna" *ngFor="let columna of columnas;">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=dataIndex;"> {{element[{{columna}}]}}</td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
```

Resumiendo:

Estas haciendo una llamada al elemento `element["columna"]`, elemento que no existe.

Al hacer una llamada a `element[{{columna}}]` que sería lo mismo que poner
`element["ciudad"]` > `element["vehiculos.turismo"]` > etc.

Comment: Gracias por contestar.
Si utilizo la expresión que me indicas da error de sintaxis.
Si utilizo`{{element[columna]}}` no da error, los valores de la propiedad `ciudad` los pinta, pero los de `vehiculos.turismo` no.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: Para solucionarlo hice un reduce de las propiedades de esta forma queda:
En tablaejemplodinamica.component.ts

```
columnas:['ciudad', 'vehiculos.turismo', 'vehiculos.todoterreno', "vehiculos.camiones"];

damePropiedades= (obj, path) => (
  path.split('.').reduce((o, p) => o && o[p], obj)
)
```

y en tablaejemplodinamica.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="datos" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="columna" *ngFor="let columna of columnas;">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columna}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;"> {{damePropiedades(element, columna)}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
</mat-table>
```